# Timeout: request did not complete within allowed duration

Tags: kubernetes

I encountered some problems when I used kubernetes' Initializers to enable LXCFS.

**ENV:** Kernel 3.10, centos7.5, k8s1.11.3

After deploying [lxcfs-initializer](https://github.com/denverdino/lxcfs-initializer/issues/3) with daemonset,when i add the annotations: `"initializer.kubernetes.io/lxcfs": "true"` in yaml, the container run successful.

However, without this annotation, when I try to create a deployment, it gives following error:

```
[root@master1 ~]# kubectl apply -f test.yaml 
service/nginx-service created
Error from server (Timeout): error when creating "test.yaml": Timeout: request did not complete within allowed duration
```

Here, is my `test.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx 
        image: nginx:1.14 
        imagePullPolicy: Always 
        ports: 
        - name: service-port
          containerPort: 80 
        resources: 
          requests: 
            memory: "250Mi"
            cpu: "0.5"
          limits: 
            memory: "500Mi"
            cpu: "1"
        volumeMounts:
            - name: timezone
              mountPath: /etc/localtime
      restartPolicy: Always 
      volumes:
        - name: timezone
          hostPath:
            path: /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Shanghai
```

Also, `lxcfs-initializer` is running,

```
[root@master1 ~]# kubectl get pods
NAME                                 READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
lxcfs-cn76r                          1/1       Running   0          1h
lxcfs-initializer-647c5fb868-7mkfg   1/1       Running   0          1h
lxcfs-v75qt                          1/1       Running   0          1h
lxcfs-x5jdl                          1/1       Running   0          1h
```

Comment: link:https://github.com/denverdino/lxcfs-initializer

Comment: or how do you isolate /proc？

Comment: At first, make sure `lxcfs-daemonset` is running. then deploy `lxcfs-initializer` and finally your test daemonset.

Comment: lxcfs-daemonset and lxcfs-initializer are running,and the test.yaml is a deployment.

Comment: Can you check logs for this deployment before it fails?